# Change 500+ Classes that consumes an interface that I just modified

Tags: vb.net

I just changed an interface that is implemented by 500+ classes by adding a sub.

This generated 500+ errors in the IDE because the sub is not implemented in the classes.

Is there an easy way to get add the sub to all the classes without manually opening each one and pasting a bare bone sub?

Comment: Sounds like you need "Find and Replace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those 500 classes should have derived from a common abstract base class, where you would add the stub.